# The open sets in Banach space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces. And we set $X\times Y=\{(x, y): x\in X$ and $ y\in Y\}$. If we take a open set $U$ in $X\times Y$, then does $U$ has the form $U_{X}\times U_{Y}$? Here $U_{X}$ and $U_{Y}$ are the open sets in $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider $X=Y=\Bbb R$, and consider $U$ any open set in the plane which is not a rectangle. Can you think of one?

(More generally, ask yourself when the union of two rectangles is a rectangle. Thinking about that will admit a myriad of counterexamples.)

Comment: Perhaps I should point out that $\Bbb R$ is a Banach space. Just a very trivial one.

Comment: I can think of a more trivial one.

Comment: Daniel, the null space? Hardly an answer to the question though!

Comment: Right. Too trivial for the argument to work, for if one of the factors is that trivial, then all open sets in the product are rectangles.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Oh, yes, but if $U$ is a open set in $X\times Y$, can we find $U_{X}\times U_{Y}$ contained in $U$?

Comment: @Belle-tiantian: Rectangles form a basis to the product, so yes. But $U_X$ and $U_Y$ are usually not the projections of $U$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila What is the projections of $U$?

Comment: The projection of $A\subseteq X\times Y$ to $X$ is the set $\{x\in X\mid \exists y(\langle x,y\rangle\in A)\}$, and similarly we define the projection of $A$ on $Y$. Do you really not know that? This is the first thing people should see when they learn about the product topology: it is the coarsest topology for which projections are continuous.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Oh, thanks for your patience. :)